# Parameter names when defining abstract functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some abstract base class that defines abstract functions. For example (barebones),

```
abstract class My_Foo extends CI_Model {
  $protected a;
  $protected b;
  abstract public printWithExtra($extra);
}

class Bar extends My_Foo {
  public printWithExtra($param) {
    echo $this->a, $this->b, $param;
  }
}
```

Does it matter what I name the parameter when implementing the abstract function?
I don't believe it should, but I'm feeling a bit paranoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my knowledge goes, it does not matter what you name the parameter within the function.

Whether you name it $param or $data or $value, it does not matter since the variable is only available withing the function and not within the class or global scope. 
however it is always good practice to copy the same naming as the abstract class. It will make your application more readable over time.

Comment: Thank you! Just had to be sure.